# GreenDAO 3.1.1 Annotation processing fails at "[Type] cannot be resolved to a variable"

Tags: java, android, greendao

Any help or guidance would be great; I've recently starting working with GreenDAO (version 3.1.1) using their new annotation processor rather than using the generation projects as the previous versions employed.

All goes well until I try to add custom constructors with class type parameters, or reference other class type functions within the class.

I am met with the following error:

```
Found 1 problem(s) parsing "C:\~\authentication\providers\AuthenticationToken.java":
Pb(83) AuthenticationProviderTypes cannot be resolved to a variable
:jroot:greendao FAILED
```

I'm using:

```
- GreenDAO 3.1.1
- Android Studio 2.1.3
- buildToolsVersion 23.0.3
- targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
- compileSdkVersion/targetSdkVersion 24
- minSdkVersion 19
```

What I've tried:

```
- Invalidate cache / restart android studio
- Clean build (like infinity times)
- Removing the custom constructor 
    - Does build, but defeats the point of needing constructor.
- Read through the documentation and added the @Keep annotation.
```

Here's a shortened example of my entity class:

```
@Entity(nameInDb = "authentication_token", active = true, createInDb = true)
public final class AuthenticationToken implements Serializable {
    @Unique
    @Id(autoincrement = false)
    private Long id;

    @SerializedName("InstanceAuthenticationType")
    @Convert(converter = AuthenticationProviderTypes.AuthenticationProviderTypeConverter.class, columnType = Integer.class)
    private AuthenticationProviderTypes authenticationType;

    @SerializedName("CustomerCode")
    @Convert(converter = CustomerCode.CustomerCodeConverter.class, columnType = String.class)
    private CustomerCode customerCode;

    @SerializedName("ContactCode")
    @Convert(converter = ContactCode.ContactCodeConverter.class, columnType = String.class)
    private ContactCode contactCode;

    @SerializedName("PortalID")
    private Integer portalID;

    @Generated(hash = 1522783431)
    public AuthenticationToken(Long id, 
        AuthenticationProviderTypes authenticationType, 
        CustomerCode customerCode, 
        ContactCode contactCode, 
        Integer portalID) {
        // generated constructor code; this is fine, works & builds like a champ!
    }

    @Keep
    public AuthenticationToken(AuthenticationProviderTypes preferredProviderType) {
        // After successful build without this constructor
        // I add this constructor to the entity class
        // and it causes the GreenDAO generator / build to fail.
        // without any other changes to the class or code
        authenticationType = preferredProviderType;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: I'm wondering if this problem is limitation or bug. I removed my custom constructor, created my class instance from the generated empty constructor and set my variable using the generated setter. It works, but goes against the point of having a concrete constructor in an object's logic. I feel this demonstrates the generator knows about and can resolve my AuthenticationProviderTypes class, just not at the constructor level.

Thanks again for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let GreenDao generate its methods .. then implement serializable or parcelable.

Im deleting all generated methods, then call

```
./gradlew greendao
```

Comment: I found also that sometimes on an ENTITY change, i need to do an invalidate/clear cache & restart, then do a clean build. It seems to be a caching issue. Also, if a method is already created, but greendao tries to generate its own copy (for entity links like toOne or toMany), it freaks out as well. +1 for responding, thanks!